# Discriminant analysis splitting data

Tags: r

I would like to analyze the data set `data(wine)` which is available in the R package `gclus`.
How can I split the data set according to the proportions 70:30 into a training and a test set?

Comment: Try `n1 <- ceiling(nrow(wine) * 0.7);training <- wine[seq_len(n1),];
 test <- wine[n1:nrow(wine),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your data like this:

```
library(gclus)
data("wine")
sample_size <- floor(0.70 * nrow(wine))
set.seed(123)
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(wine)), size = sample_size)
train <- wine[train_index, ]
test <- wine[-train_index, ]
```

Checking the sizes of the datasets:

```
> nrow(wine)
[1] 178
> nrow(train)
[1] 124
> nrow(test)
[1] 54
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach to @Quinten very good approach:
First we create an `id` for each row and use `sample_frac()` to finally `anti_join()` original `wine` with the `train_wine`:

```
#install.packages("gclus")
library(gclus)
library(dplyr)
data("wine")

wine <- wine %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())
  
train_wine <- wine %>% 
  sample_frac(.70)

test_wine <- anti_join(wine, train_wine, by = 'id')

nrow(train_wine)
nrow(test_wine)
```

Comment: Go and try out. Read about `MASS` here <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf>